# Jquery: closest() with other div class not working

Tags: jquery, closest

I cant understand, why the closest()  not working with other div class selector. Please see example: Thanks for any help

```
<div class="level1">Some Text</div>
<div class="level1">Some Text 2</div> 
<div class="level2">level2 Text</div>

<div class="result">result</div>


var txt = $('.level2').closest('.level1').text();
$('.result').text("result: " + txt );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they're not nested. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches ancestors, not siblings.

If you want the closest previous sibling, that's `.prevAll(".level1").first()` ([`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/), [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)).

Live Example:

```js
var txt = $('.level2').prevAll('.level1').first().text();
$('.result').text("result: " + txt );
```

```html
<div class="level1">Some Text</div>
<div class="level1">Some Text 2</div> 
<div class="level2">level2 Text</div>

<div class="result">result</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much for help. Your Example is exactly what i searched.